# Can't install snap

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Today, I want to install the mailspring by snap. but my terminal gives me this:

[image]

How can I fix it.

My Ubuntu system below.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Frank .. welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately your question has nothing to do with programming, and is therefor off-topic. You could try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux or https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux#

Comment: See https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/basic-snap-usage#1, that can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply run
apt update
then run
apt list --upgradable
finally, run the below command to install snapd
sudo apt install snapd

***********I hope this will help************

Answer (score 0):

did you do `apt update` before trying to install the package?